# On Back press the calling activity is not shown

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having a problem. I am using an implicit intent to launch another application (sms) from my application.

I want that the control to return to my application when the user presses back in the launched(sms) application.
For now the behavior that I am observing in my application is:

Observed:

> **Activity A (MY APP) ---launches--> SMS application-----on back press---> Launcher**

Desired:

> **Activity A (MY APP) ---launches--> SMS application-----on back press---> My APP**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using startActivityForResult, after the action is performed, the result comes back to the onActivityResult method, where you can perform the desired action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             //do what you wish
        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCEL){
       //some error occured or something else        
}
```

The thing is in both cases after you're done you will get back to your activity.